# iOS: AVPlayerItem to AVAsset

Tags: ios7, avplayer, avasset, avvideocomposition

I got 2 AVAssets, and I do have change using VideoComposition, and AudioMix for AVPlayerItem. After that, I use asset from AVPlayerItem, but VideoComposition, and AudioMix are not applied.
I want the result asset to be applied by both VideoComposition, and AudioMix.
Here's the code.

```
+ (AVAsset *)InitAsset:(AVAsset *)asset AtTime:(double)start ToTime:(double)end {
CGFloat colorComponents[4] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0};

//Create AVMutableComposition Object.This object will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack.
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

//Here we are creating the first AVMutableCompositionTrack.See how we are adding a new track to our AVMutableComposition.
AVMutableCompositionTrack *masterTrack =
[mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                            preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
//Now we set the length of the firstTrack equal to the length of the firstAsset and add the firstAsset to out newly created track at kCMTimeZero so video plays from the start of the track.
[masterTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(start, 1), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(end, 1))
                     ofTrack:[[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                      atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

// Each video layer instruction
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *masterLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:masterTrack];
[masterLayerInstruction setOpacity:1.0f atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[masterLayerInstruction setOpacityRampFromStartOpacity:1.0f
                                          toEndOpacity:0.0
                                             timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(end, 1), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(end + ANIMATION_FADE_TIME, 1))];

//See how we are creating AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction object.This object will contain the array of our AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction objects.You set the duration of the layer.You should add the lenght equal to the lingth of the longer asset in terms of duration.
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
[MainInstruction setTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(end + ANIMATION_FADE_TIME, 1))];
[MainInstruction setLayerInstructions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterLayerInstruction,nil]];
[MainInstruction setBackgroundColor:CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colorComponents)];

//Now we create AVMutableVideoComposition object.We can add mutiple AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction to this object.We have only one AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction object in our example.You can use multiple AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction objects to add multiple layers of effects such as fade and transition but make sure that time ranges of the AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction objects dont overlap.
AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(1280, 720);
//    [MainCompositionInst setFra]

AVMutableCompositionTrack *masterAudio = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[masterAudio insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(end + ANIMATION_FADE_TIME, 1))
                     ofTrack:[[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

// Each Audio
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *masterAudioMix = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:masterAudio];
[masterAudioMix setVolume:1.0f atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[masterAudioMix setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:1.0f
                                 toEndVolume:0.0f
                                   timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(end, 1), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(end + ANIMATION_FADE_TIME, 1))];
//    [SecondTrackMix setVolume:1.0f atTime:CMTimeMake(2.01, 1)];

AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
audioMix.inputParameters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterAudioMix,nil];

//Finally just add the newly created AVMutableComposition with multiple tracks to an AVPlayerItem and play it using AVPlayer.
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:mixComposition];
item.videoComposition = MainCompositionInst;
item.audioMix = audioMix;

return [item asset];
}
```

Do anyone have any idea ?

Best Regards.

Comment: I don't understand this question.  Do you *want* to change something, or you have changed something but it didn't get applied?  Could you edit your question to show some code as to what you are attempting to do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I've already edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Use AVAssetExportSeesion...

"An AVAssetExportSession object transcodes the contents of an AVAsset source object to create an output of the form described by a specified export preset."

Use AVAssetExportSeesion's properties audioMix and videoComposition.

---

audioMix
Indicates whether non-default audio mixing is enabled for export, and supplies the parameters for audio mixing.

@property(nonatomic, copy) AVAudioMix *audioMix

---

videoComposition
Indicates whether video composition is enabled for export, and supplies the instructions for video composition.

@property(nonatomic, copy) AVVideoComposition *videoComposition

Comment: Can I export tham to AVAsset instead of a file ?

Comment: Not with AVAssetExportSession. Why not just use AVAsset's method + (id)assetWithURL:(NSURL *)URL?

Comment: Because I need to repeat this method, and to export to file before reopen it takes a lot of time.